# AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Missing or undefined handler: GET /test

Tags: typescript

this is my code for controller function in typescript so it giving me above error ,even though handler function is present in controller file

```
export const test  =  {
options:{
    handler: (request, reply) => {
      return reply.response({a: "Hello World"}).code(200);
    },
    plugins: {
      "hapi-swagger": {
        responses: {'200': {'description': 'OK'}
        }
      }
    },
    tags: undefined
}
}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a requires for /test route handler.

```
 { method: 'GET', path: '/test', config: MyRequireStatmentIsMissing.test },
```

Add the missing requires

```
const MyRequireStatmentIsMissing = require('./controller/test');
```

This will clear that error.